# Hide keyboard on any key press in iphone

Tags: ios

I want to hide the keyboard when i press any key other than the return key .
For example when the user presses the character 'n' on keyboard , keyboard should disappear.
Please provide me a suitable answer as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may try UIKeyInput protocol. To catch a insert with insertText
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Have you used protocols?

EDIT:
Then you can use method
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

To hide the keyboard

EDIT2: Protocols
In short, the interface for class that you want to respond to the protocol must be declare as (in YourClass.h):

```
@interface YourClass:NSObject<UIKitInput>
```

then, you have to implements the protocol methods in YourClass.m:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIKeyInput Protocol Methods

- (BOOL)hasText {
    .....
    return NO;
}

- (void)insertText:(NSString *)theText {
    ...;
}

- (void)deleteBackward {
    ....
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: No i have not used protocols.It was a task for me and i can hide the keyboard using IBAction and wiring the textfield this with did end on exit event

Comment: should i write the logic in the has text method?can you implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard hides when the text field resigns first responder. The textfield delegate is told when a key is pressed (`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`). If you need any more detail than that, please put a bit more effort into your question and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Tell me how to implement this by the use of delegates.I have used UITextFieldDelegate. Please tell me the code which i can write in my .m file.I just want to hide the keyboard when i press any key other than the return key. any key it can be a special character or a-z .

Comment: Please tell me how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Have you looked here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol.pdf

Comment: Hey please tell me atleast which method to invoke.?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to create a custom keyboard or you have to override the Keyboard methods. But you cannot override. Because You do not know, in which method and what code is to sense that key pressing in that frameworks. So better write a custom keyboard anyway.

Comment: I have to do the task on the default keyboard.Please provide me a solution or otherwise i will be fired.